# Shuffle middle characters of words in a string?

Tags: java, string

Here is the question I need to solve:

> ```
> I  dn’ot gvie a dman for a man taht can only sepll a word one way.
> ```
>
> Write a method String scramble(String word) that constructs a
>   scrambled version of a given word, randomly flipping two characters
>   other than the first and last one. Then write a program that reads
>   words from a file “input.txt”  (one word per line) and outputs the
>   each word with its scrambled version (one pair per line) to another
>   file “scrambled.txt”.

I don't need a string to be converted to words, just one word per line. I need to read words, not strings.

So far, what I've done is this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class examhelp
{
    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException
    {
        Scanner kbd=new Scanner(System.in);
        File f=new File("words.txt");
        Scanner inputFile=new Scanner(f);
        PrintWriter outputFile=new PrintWriter("scrambled.txt");
        bloop wlist=new bloop();
        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            String ww=inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(ww);
            outputFile.println(wlist.scramble(ww));
        }
        inputFile.close();
        outputFile.close();
    }
}

class bloop
{
    public static String scramble(String word)
    {
        String shuffledString = ""; 

        while (word.length() != 0)
        {
            int index = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length());
            char c = word.charAt(index);
            word = word.substring(0,index)+word.substring(index+1);
            shuffledString += c;
        }

        return shuffledString;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, it shuffles ALL the letters, including the first and last, and I cant' do that according to the question. Can you please help me with my method and what exact code should be there? I can take a look at it and see where I was wrong and what I needed to do. Thanks.

I need to do it WITHOUT the arrays or any pre-defined methods.

Comment: It looks to me like the assignment is asking for all of the _words_ to be scrambled, just not the first and last _characters_ in each word.  Please edit to clarify.

Comment: looks like ... after you get a line of your text, you will need to break it to list of words : you could use the split() with white space delimiter. then don't send the first and last words in the list .. The ugly part is you will need to construct the whole text with the first +  scrambled + last :(

Comment: Also, I see you've named your class `"examhelp"`.  Is this an exam question?

Comment: @Floegipoky Sample Exam worksheet you have before exams.

Comment: @LeTex My file has one word per line so that's not a problem. It's scrambling it perfectly but it's scrambling letters randomly, including first and last, which should be untouched.

Comment: it is straight forward then .. when you get index using random() make sure that it will NOT return 0 or word.length() .. that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by taking your existing `scramble` method and making it `private`; we'll also alter it to take two additional arguments (both of type `char`) like

```
private static String scramble(char first, char last, String word)
{
    String shuffledString = "" + first; // <-- add the first char
    while (word.length() != 0)
    {
        int index = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length());
        char c = word.charAt(index);
        word = word.substring(0,index)+word.substring(index+1);
        shuffledString += c;
    }
    return shuffledString + last; // <-- add the last char
}
```

Then we can use that method to implement a `public` version that scrambles *the middle* like

```
public static String scramble(String word) {
    if (word.length() < 3) {
        return word;
    }
    String middle = word.substring(1, word.length() - 1);
    return scramble(word.charAt(0), word.charAt(word.length() - 1), middle);
}
```

**Edit** Also, as pointed out below; you're using

```
String ww=inputFile.nextLine();
```

but your loop is on `Scanner.hasNext()`. If you change that to [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)

```
String ww=inputFile.next();
```

you should get white-space seperated tokens instead of line(s).

Comment: I think you are focusing on letters in a word while his question is words in a sentence.

Comment: @LeTex Good catch. I missed that OP was using `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am using letters in a word, sorry for the confusion. Each line as ONLY one word, and that word needs to be scrambled except the first and last letters of that word, like you said, just the middle. Then the loop moves on to the next word. :)

It was exactly what I needed, it works, now the only thing I need is to figure out what you did :P

Comment: @AbhishekIndoria I suggest you use `hasNextLine()` with `nextLine()`. As for what I did, I commented the only things I changed...

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** I hope you understand that candidate words to be shuffled must have at least 4 characters; you omit smaller words by just returning them as they are.

**Step 2:** Choose a random index other than first and last one.

**Step 3:** flip this random selected character with the one in each right.

*Performance Hint 1:* You can also slightly improve in performance by omitting the semifinal index too. No need to select and flip the semifinal character as the final one (which is omitted) is in each right.

*Performance Hint 2:* Or you can omit the second index from random selection (index=1) and always flip with one on the left, do you see why?

This implementation is pretty easy, but I leave it to you as it is an assignment.

Comment: Not an assignment, just a worksheet, but I figured it out, thank you. :)